# query with both whereArrayContains() and whereIn() not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## ******UPDATE:******

I made a really bad mistake, I thought `whereIn()` worked with arrays but it's intended use is for checking if a field's value matches one of the values in the array that's passed to it. If anyone's also having this problem, check out the docs, they explain it pretty well, that's what I should've done, and lesson learned because I got pretty stressed out. [Here's link to docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any), make sure to look at the example data at the top, that's what I missed and why I didn't understand why the query wasn't working. Leaving this here in case someone runs into this too.

## ******ORIGINAL QUESTION:******

I'm testing if I can use a query with both `whereArrayContains()` and `whereIn()`, but its not working, and the documentation doesn't say it's not permitted. I already created necessary composite indexes, and checked spelling of everything like 5 times, but I still have no idea why it's not working.

Here's my query:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("collection")
            .whereArrayContains("flags.explicit", "?")
            .whereIn("keys", Arrays.asList("?"))
            .orderBy("saves", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(1)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "success, snapshot size: " + queryDocumentSnapshots.size());
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "failed to do stuff", e));
```

when I test the query there's no error, and snapshot size is always 0, even though I added some test docs with values that should be a match, any idea what it could be?

## Edit: test doc structure with relevant data:

```
doc
 |---flags
 |     |---explicit: [false, "?"]
 |---keys: ["value1", "value2", "?"]
 |---saves: 9
```

the purpose of "?" is to behave sort of like a wildcard so there doesn't have to be an index for content that isn't explicit, and for content that doesn't matter if is explicit or not